Open another sharepoint page onclick on Modal PopUp
I would like to open another page by click on the button from Landing page, I have followed the below suggestion. Looks like it only works on 2013 but not on sharepoint online.
I am adding this script in modern scrip editor.
I have tried to debug this issue found that sp is not found. Any idea how to create the modal pop to load another sharepoint page inside modal.
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);

How to make a Modal popup when someone clicks a link on my page

This code works only in classic experience (included SharePoint Online in Microsoft 365), not with the modern experience.

@jleture are there any resource which would help in this scenario or javascript ?

Please try to embed PnP IFrameDialog control which could display web page in a dialog in the SPFx extension.
For more information, please refer to:
https://ravichandran.blog/2020/05/24/popup-documents-using-pnp-iframedialog-control-in-spfx/
https://github.com/kongmengfei/SharedSPFx/blob/master/modaldialog/src/webparts/modaldialog/components/Modaldialog.tsx
Similar issue:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0db7ccb-3be1-4e8b-9a04-55a96d251a49/open-modal-dialog-from-spfx-web-part-in-sharepoint-online-modern-site?forum=onlineservicessharepoint
